# How to locate address of a function using base address of the executable?

Tags: c, windows, kernel

OK so I have the base address of **ntoskrnl.exe** and want to locate the address of an internal function that is neither exported or imported. How can this be done in kernel mode ?

Comment: The best option is to not do it. Even using symbols is risky.

Comment: @Anders thank you. I'm just doing this for fun. This code will not make it into any product for the consumer market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pattern scan for the function, or it has a static RVA. There are many ways, but the easiest is by creating a signature (for example with SigMaker in IDA Pro) and scanning for it inside your module.

For exported routines this is much easier:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress

For within a specific module, you can manually walk the EAT (Export Address Table).

Comment: LucasBreeden@ can you tell me how can a pattern scan be done ? I have the base address of ntoskrnl.exe but do not know the offset of the function. But whenever I try the following statement if (*(pNtBase + i) == pPatch_Info.Signature[j]) my code crashes the system. BSOD PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA in my kernel mode driver. Any ideas ?

Comment: @JonnyBGood You're dereferencing an invalid memory address, you'll have to fix the logic yourself as I don't know how you do it